# Don't show latest content on frontpage

Tags: nodes

How do I make it so Drupal doesn't automatically show latest content on frontpage?

Answer (score 2):

One way -- possibly the easiest way -- is to create a page containing whatever you want to be displayed on the home page, then going to `www.yoursite.com/?q=admin/config/system/site-information` if you're using Drupal 7 (or `www.yoursite.com/?q=admin/settings/site-information` if you're using Drupal 6), and then changing *Default front page* from `node` to `node/1` (assuming the page you created was normally located at `www.example.com/node/1`).

Answer (score 2):

The best way depends on what you want on your home page.

If you want a page of content, then creating a node and setting it to the home page at admin/config/system/site-information is the best way.

However if you just want a page of blocks, with no node content, there are better ways.
This is because creating a blank page and assigning it to the home page is a bit of a hack, and it means the system is wasting resources doing the node load and everything else that goes with it, for an empty node.

So instead you could use:

- [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) - Add a panels page and assign blocks where you want
  them.
- [Empty page](http://drupal.org/project/empty_page) - Allows you to create empty pages, by
  assigning them a path and a page title. You can then assign blocks
  using drupal core blocks or using the [context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module.
- [Front page](http://drupal.org/project/front) - Allows you to do a bunch of things, like set the home page
  content, or set the page to use for the front page. The only real
  reason to use this one is that is allows different front pages per
  role. So if for example you want a different home page for logged in
  users, use this module.

Then after you have one of those module set up, you can set the front page to your panels page/empty page at admin/config/system/site-information.